# Using SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format in an SQL Query

Tags: java, oracle10g, simpledateformat

Is it possible to use SimpleDateFormat like so in the following SQL query?

```
SELECT empnumber WHERE compname = 'mycomp' ORDER BY new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(genfield), emppnumber asc
```

A friend once told me it was possible, but all I'm getting is an error:

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer for this, and will eventually put it in a Java program when / if it succeeds.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use Javas `SimpleDateFormat` in plain SQL.

You can either use it in the Java programm and concatenate the query string with the `SimpleDateFormat.format()` result or you can just use the Oracle sql function `TO_DATE()`

Like this:

```
SELECT empnumber WHERE compname = 'mycomp' ORDER BY TO_DATE(genfield, 'MM/dd/yyyy'), emppnumber asc;
```

Comment: @zack_falcon: Of what type is `genfield`? Is it just a date or a string which contains a date? Could you give me an example entry of your table?

Comment: It's supposed to be of Varchar type. However some nutjob on my team decided it would be fine and dandy to have the software we programmed to populate it with... characters.

Comment: Okay and it only contains a varchar in the format 'MM/dd/yyyy'? You say 'TO_DATE() doesn't work.' What error do you get?

Comment: No, actually. I see a '0' or '1' in there. Hundreds of them. Yikes. Thanks anyway. I just thought there might be a query that could filter out items that can not be converted to DateTime.

Comment: Maybe you can. I actually belive you can. But I have to know what format it is exactly. Can you post a single value of this column? (I think one value shouldn't be a problem with data privacy)

Comment: The data field is a VARCHAR. Because of that, and the beta nature of the program we developed, it had anything from dates to names and numbers, which forces the TO_DATE to throw out an error when converting said name to a DATE. A serious oversight on my team mate's part. I've asked another question concerning my proposed solution on this - which is to ignore results that couldn't be converted into DATEs.